# Cannot find symbol class PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, android

I have the following declaration:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager manager;
```

and Android Studio return me the error:

Error:(113, 9) error: cannot find symbol class PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

Also I have imported: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager as say http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html but Android Studio doesn't detect it.

What can I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the Apache library in your classpath?

Comment: I guess because I am using other utilities from apache library such as org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme or org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

I need use the apache library from apache repository

I have needed add:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
```

to my build.grade as says in https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html